# CSS Error with a span

Tags: css

I'm trying to use a span to show a small icon next to some text inside a table. Here's the html code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span class="icon">&nbsp;</span>
    Bob Smith
  </td>
</tr>
```

CSS code:

```
.icon
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-image: url(../images/icon.png);
}
```

All I want is a small checkbox icon (15x15px) to be showed right next to the name, in this format:

```
[icon]Bob Smith
```

However, right now its showing as:

```
[icon]           Bob Smith
```

(I.e there's a lot of whitespace between the icon and the text)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: is this hapenning only in IE ? , i tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/CpUUg/ and its working fine

Comment: You sure the table cell doesn't have a `text-align: center;` style on it?

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle of your issue, or perhaps give us a live link? We're basically just guessing from a number of things that could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicity setting a `width` on the `icon` class, such as this:

```
.icon
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float:left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-image: url(../images/icon.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="icon"></span> Bob Smith
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS code:

```
.icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/icon.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 15px;
    height:15px;
    margin-right:4px;/*to put a slight buffer between icon and text*/
}
```

Comment: How do you figure? What other styles do you have on the page? There's no reason this would make the icon disappear as long as the path is correct.

Comment: Nevermind, the icon is back, but its the same way as before, not close to the text

Comment: Remove the margin-right, I added that for spacing, but if you want the icon directly next to the text then it's not needed. You can also add align="left" to the table or td.